# Merge Sort (Explanation for using k = l in the merge function

Tags: c++11

Why we use k=l in merge function? The code is given below,
I tried analysing the code by using some print statements

```
`void merge(int arr[], int l, int mid, int r){
    int n1 = mid-l+1;
    int n2 = r-mid;
    int a1[n1], a2[n2];
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){a1[i]=arr[l+i];}
    // int t=0;
    for(int i=0; i < n2; i++){a2[i] = arr[mid+1+i];}
    int i=0,j=0,k=l;
    while(i<n1 && j <n2){
        if(a1[i]<a2[j]){
            arr[k++] = a1[i++];
        }
        else{
            arr[k++] = a2[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<n1){arr[k++]=a1[i++];}
    while(j<n2){arr[k++]=a2[j++];}
}
void merge_sort(int *arr, int si, int ei){
    if(si >= ei)return;
    int mid = (si + ei)/2;
    std::cout<<"si: "<<si<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ei: "<<ei<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"mid: "<<mid<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
    merge_sort(arr, si, mid);
    std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
    merge_sort(arr, mid+1, ei);
    std::cout<<"3"<<std::endl;
    merge(arr, si, mid, ei);
}`
# merge sort
```

Thanks.

Why we use int k=l, in the merge function?

Comment: `k` is an index into `arr` where sorted elements are being written after merge. You want the first (smallest) element to be written to `arr[l]`, hence `k` is initialized to `l`. What do you believe it should have been initialized to instead, and why?

Answer (score 0):

At some point you may call `merge_sort(arr,l,m,r)` (l<m<r).

Further recursive calls generates two sorted sub arrays: `arr[l:m]` and `arr[m+1:r]`. You then need to merge these two into `arr[l:r]`.

The algorithm creates two temporary lists `a1` and `a2` that respectively contain elements of `arr[l:m]` and `arr[m+1:r]` before the merging and then merge them into `arr[l:r]`.

It fills `arr[l:r]` starting with `k=l`(increasing `k` at each step) and setting `arr[k]` to either an element of `a1` or an element of `a2` (with respective moving indexes `i` and `j`).